# As a client app, how do I get the 'x-amzn-oidc-*' headers forwaded to me from Amazon Load Balancers (ALB)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I'm planning on setting up ALB (Amazon Load Balancer) for authentication. It'll sit in front of my client app and only forward authenticated requests with the access_token and user claim jwt's as headers, `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken` + `x-amzn-oidc-data` respectively [0].

My client application will need to capture these forwarded headers and store them in localStorage for accessing other AWS resources in later requests (ex. S3).

If I'm the client app receiving the ALB request, how would I intercept these headers? Would they come in as a request or response?

[0] See step #10 in the diagram: https://www.exampleloadbalancer.com/auth_detail.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These headers wouldn't be received by your client by default.  The client makes a request to the ALB and, after the user is authenticated, the ALB would pass the headers to your backend.

If the client needs these headers, your backend could add them to the response headers and your client could then retrieve them there.

That being said, keep in mind that if you do return these headers to the client, that anyone using some simple browser debug tools can see the headers and then craft their own requests using them.  It may be better add the functionality that you need to the backend so that no credentials are potentially exposed to users.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. How would the client grab the incoming request headers via javascript? Or would future client requests to my backend include these headers by default?

Comment: I reread your question, as I think I misunderstood. 

If you client app needs these headers than you would need to include them in your response somehow.  Perhaps your backend would need to add them as HTTP headers to the response and your clients can pull them from there.

Comment: Adding follow up for posterity. My problem was that I couldn't test to see what headers the ALB was passing through, locally (I didn't have a dev env at the time). Eventually I was able to grab the headers from the backend using express.